# (Linear algebra): Why is this not not onto?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> $ T: P_2(R) \rightarrow P_3(R) ; T(f(x)) = xf(x) + f'(x)$

I then selected basis $\beta = 1 + x + x^2$ as a basis for V. Then calculating for basis for R(T):

$$R(T) = {\rm span}(T(B) ) 
=  {\rm span} (T(1), T(x), T(x^2) )
=  {\rm span}( (x+0), (x^2+1), (x^3+2x) ) $$

Hence, I found basis for $R(T)=  \{(x), (x^2+1), (x^3+2x)\}$. I then said that since ${\rm Rank}(T) = 4 = \dim(W)$, then $T$ was onto. However, my answer scheme tells me that $T$ is not onto.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could point out where I went wrong!

Comment: How did you conclude $Rank(T) = 4$?

Comment: What is $V$, what is $B$? How can the image have dimension $4$ if you only have one element in the basis?

Comment: What is $B$ and  what is $V$?

Comment: @juanrroyo Hi there! I made the mistake of thinking that each $x$ in $\beta$ counted as an element, which was rather silly of me. I now see that Dim(W)=4 and Rank(T)=3, and so T cannot be onto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing $\beta = 1+x+x^2$ as a basis is wrong - The correct would be $\beta=\{1,x,x^2\}$, since $1+x+x^2$ is a single polynomial in the space.

Indeed $R(T)$ is spanned by the vectors you wrote, but these vectors do not span all of $P_3(\Bbb R)$, since there only are three vectors and $\dim P_3(\Bbb R) = 4$. This argument actually shows that there is **no** surjective linear map from $P_2(\Bbb R)$ to $P_3(\Bbb R)$.

Comment: Adding to last comments, note that if $\deg f=n$, and $f\ne 0$, then $\deg (T f) = n+1$. In particular, no nonzero polynomials of degree $0$ (constant functions) are in the range of $T$.

Comment: OH, now I see where I went wrong. I was assuming that each $x$ counted as an element in the basis. I see now that Rank(T) isn't equal Dim(W).

Thanks! Sorry for the silly question